# Is there a way to make ordered list items appear faster in incremental mode in Rmarkdown ioslides?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides, slidy

I am using Rmarkdown ioslides. I do not like how slow bullet points appear in the incremental mode. Is there a way to speed them up?

I am looking for something similar Slidy presentations. In slidy bullet points appear instantaneously when you click on the mouse.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the transition properties of the CSS.  Create a file called `delays.css`, and put this into it:

```
.build > * {
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
```

Those are the default values.  Change the numbers to make things faster or slower.  For example, changing all the numbers to `0.0s` will make things instant.  There are other possible values for `ease-in-out`, but with no transition time they won't make any difference.  If you want to read about them, look here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition .

To make your slides use it, add this to your YAML:

```
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    incremental: true
    css:  delays.css
```